# auto update NVD3 graph in Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to create a reusable graph using Angular and NVD3. In the code below the graphs are displaying fine, but I'm not sure how to redraw them when the data changes. When I hover over the first bar, the updated value is displayed, but the graph itself doesn't change.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.1.13-beta/nv.d3.css">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.2.2/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.1.13-beta/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.js"></script>
<script>

'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function AppCtrl ($scope, $http) {

 $scope.data = [{
  values: [{x:0,y:1},{x:1,y:2},{x:2,y:4},{x:3,y:1}],
  key: 'first',
  color: '#ff7f0e'
 },
 {
  values: [{x:0,y:3},{x:1,y:8},{x:2,y:4},{x:3,y:2}],
  key: 'second',
  color: '#2ca02c'
 }];
 
 $scope.data2 = [{
  values: [{x:0,y:1},{x:1,y:20},{x:2,y:4},{x:3,y:1}],
  key: 'first',
  color: '#ff7f0e'
 },
 {
  values: [{x:0,y:3},{x:1,y:8},{x:2,y:4},{x:3,y:2}],
  key: 'second',
  color: '#2ca02c'
 }];

});

app.directive('ghVisualization', function () {

 var w = 800;
 var h = 300;
 var margin = 10;

 return {
  restrict: 'E',
  terminal: true,
  scope: {
   val: '='
  },
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

   var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
    .transitionDuration(350)
    .reduceXTicks(true)
    .rotateLabels(0)
    .showControls(false)
    .groupSpacing(0.1);

   chart.xAxis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

   chart.yAxis
    .tickFormat(d3.format(',.1f'));

   var svg = d3.select(element[0])
    .append("svg")
    .datum(scope.val)
    .call(chart);

  }
 }
});

</script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<form>
<input type="text" ng-model="data[0].values[0].y"> {{data[0].values[0].y}}
</form>
<gh-visualization val="data"></gh-visualization>
<gh-visualization val="data2"></gh-visualization>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem appears to be solved as follows:

```
var svg = d3.select(element[0])
    .append("svg");

scope.render = function(data) {
    svg
        .datum(data)
        .call(chart);
}

scope.$watch('val', function() {
    scope.render(scope.val);
}, true);
```

Any remarks or suggestions are stil welcome.